# Mailto link in document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2016, email, url

I'm trying to add a `mailto` link in a SharePoint document library.

I created a new Link to document, I gave it a name "something" and in the URL I put `http://..../something.aspx`.  Since I can only use an address starting with `http`.

Then in the properties, the name is `something`.aspx and I changed the URL to `mailto:email@adress.com`.

When I do test the link, it works and it opens the email client.

However, when I go back to my library of documents and I click on the name, it only brings me to the blank page `something.aspx`.

It does not redirect to the URL. In comparison, if I put something like `http://something/excelFile.xls` it works and it opens excel.

I'm working on SharePoint server 2016.

Comment: Can you please clarify:  is this a custom, calculated column you are putting the email address into?  What is the name of the column that the email is being entered into?

Answer (score 0):

email@adress.com will not work in "Link to document" content type:

[image]

Please refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/472675/sharepoint-34link-to-document34-file-in-sharepoint.html